# Insert hyperlink into column with data

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to insert hyperlinks on column A which has data. for example, A1 is the title; A2 will be 12345 with hyperlink of http://123.1.1.1/?id=12345

Currently I am running the macro on a worksheet that contains around 11000 rows. it's been about an hour, it is still running...

Also, trying to see if this single macro can work on ALL worksheets.

Below is my macro

```
Sub AddUrlSheet1()
With Worksheets(1)

Set R = ActiveSheet.Range("a2", ActiveSheet.Range("a2").End(xlDown))
R.Select

For Each R In Selection.Cells

.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=R, _
Address="http://123.1.1.1/" & R.Value

Next R
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You would want to set ScreenUpdating to False before running this, that would speed it up. Impossible to tell how long it will take!

Comment: You might want to have a look at the HYPERLINK worksheet function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub AddUrlSheet1()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    '
    Dim LastUsedRow As Long
    Dim r As Range, c As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        LastUsedRow = .Columns("A").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Set r = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LastUsedRow, 1))
    End With
    '
    For Each c In r
        c.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:="http://123.1.1.1/" & c.Value
    Next c
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This adds hyperlinks to all cells which currently have values in them in column A.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping cell by cell, use `Hyperlink()` with `Formula` to get it done. If your `R` values are in column A, this will fill in the hyperlinks in column B.

```
Sub t()
Dim rng As Range
' Note: Update the `10` to match your lastRow
Set rng = Range("B2:B" & ActiveSheet.Range("a2").End(xlDown).Row)

rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK(""http://123.1.1.1/""&RC[-1],""Link"")"

End Sub
```

If you HAVE to iterate over your already existing data, @Chris's answer looks pretty good.

Comment: Thanks, so I can't use the same column A can't be reused?

Comment: @yu2bike - What do you mean? I just meant that if you column A has values such as "1.2.3", "12.203.2", etc. then this macro will place the hyperlink in column B. The macro in your OP goes through column A, and places the link over the cell, AFAIK.

Comment: I meant to ask, if I can't use column B another column for hyperlink, then I will have to use my original route? (looping cell by cell?)

Comment: If you can't use column B, but can place the link in say column Z, then just change the column in `rng`. If you have to loop over your column A, and replace that text with a hyperlink, then yes you need to loop by cell.

Comment: Thank you @BruceWayne, after trying out. I think your method works better when I have thousands of the rows of data to loop through.

Looping kills the application..